# How does a single getter call get chosen by a node if there's no reward associated?

Tags: transactions, gas, contract-invocation, evm

A tx uses gas to incentivize being picked up by a node. On the other hand, a getter doesn't. It just returns the value.

How does a single getter call get chosen by a node if there's no reward associated?

Example: [I can query for free all the getters of USDT](https://etherscan.io/token/0xdac17f958d2ee523a2206206994597c13d831ec7#readContract)

Answer (score 1):

Only transactions are distributed to the miners to be executed.

The calls to view functions are executed by the web3 provider. If you run your own node the query will be executed locally, if you use a web3 provider like Infura the query will be executed by their nodes.